# Creating resizable XAML for WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I am somewhat new to WPF and cannot figure out how to make my UserControl re-sizable.

I have tried using a ViewBox around my main grid and that did not work. I have also tried setting every component's HorizontalAllignment and VerticalAlignment to "Stretch" and their height and width to "auto" and that did not work either. When the window is maximized, the application stays in the center of the window surrounded by blank white space.

Below is my XAML code without any alterations to make it resizable, if someone could at least point me in the right direction in terms of steps to make this window resizable

[Here is the XAML for the User Control](http://pastebin.com/0n7fcZNd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main grid there is set to a fixed width:

```
<Grid Width="1000">
```

You also seem to have alot of other fixed widths/heights in your xaml. You should probably consider redesigning that to use percentages as you have done in some other places.

Comment: Ok! What do you mean by percentages?

Comment: Well maybe I should call them ratios rather than percentages, but what I'm referring to is the star notation you use for grid column/row sizes. (Width="3*" etc). But in your case, that grid should probably have no width set at all!

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! I'm starting to get this to work thanks to your insight.  I was underestimating the amount of effort that it takes for this to be accomplished!